# How to pass a date-like argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, terminal

I want to,pass a j argument where j= date +%d%m%Y in my shell script, so how to pass that inside for loop

```
#!/bin/sh
for ((i=1;i<=25;i++))
do
  wget --output-document=$i.jpg http://sambadepaper.com/epaperimages/$j/$j-md-sa-$i.jpg/
done
xdg-open 1.jpg
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: You're not setting j in that script?

Comment: when I set j in for loop it showing error that operand missing.....so is there any other way

Comment: I'd suggest using a date format like `%Y%m%d` since they have the useful property that they sort correctly even with a normal lexicographic sort. Or the ISO 8601 style `%Y-%m-%d` since it's additionally easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date does not change all that often, so initialising j outside the loop would be fine.

`%d%m%Y` is like `22082020`, so quoting would not be an issue, although I would recommend double-quoting your whole URL anyway.

You just need to set j before the `for` loop, like:

```
j="$( date '+%d%m%Y' )"
```

although again I would use a more meaningful name.